# Route template not found in Camel context

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

I'm working on a Spring Boot / Apache Camel integration service.

- Spring Boot Version: 2.7.6
- Camel version: 3.20.2 (also tried 3.16.0)

I started experimenting with route templates and I'm running into a strange issue. When running and testing from my IDE (Eclipse or Intellij), everything works great. I can create routes from route templates without issue. However, when running the service from a Docker container, I get the following error on startup:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find RouteTemplate with id listRegisteredServicesTemplate

Here is my route template:

```java
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    
    routeTemplate("listRegisteredServicesTemplate")
        .templateParameter("routeId")
        .templateParameter("filterString")
        .from("direct:{{routeId}}")
        .description("Provides filtered list of services registered to Consul")
        .to("direct:anotherRoute")
        .enrich();
```

And here is the route implementation:

```java
@Component
public class ProcessModelRoutes extends RouteBuilder {

@Autowired
CamelContext camelContext;

@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    
    TemplatedRouteBuilder.builder(camelContext, "listRegisteredServicesTemplate")
        .routeId("aRoute")
        .parameter("routeId", "v1.com.xxx.aRoute")
        .parameter("filterString", "filter=ServiceID matches Pool")
        .add();
```

I have also tried the DLS version of the TemplateRouteBuilder. Any idea why a route template would not show up in the Camel context. Is it possibly an ordering issue? Ex... the Camel context tries to create the route implementation before the template is registered? Thanks!

Comment: MCVE please https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Try to use `templatedRoute` instead of `TemplatedRouteBuilder` like in this example https://github.com/apache/camel-spring-boot-examples/blob/main/routetemplate/src/main/java/sample/camel/MyTemplateBuilder.java#L39-L46

Comment: @NicolasFilotto As far as I can tell, Camel 3.0.0 through 4.0.0-RC2 has a bug with  Spring XML that stops `templatedRoute` declared in Java DSL in `RouteBuilder` classes annotated with `@Component` (Spring's annotation) from being added to the `CamelContext`. The `installRoutes()` method of `AbstractCamelContextFactoryBean` doesn't call `getContext().addTemplatedRoutes(routeBuilder)` for each `RouteBuilder` like it needs to.